# Iterating in a foreach loop

Tags: c#

I have used a different approach to get this GUI working. I've used User Control and needed seperate images to load in each PictureBox by iterating over my "Artists". The thing is that I think this is very ugly code, and could be done in a better way, but this works just fine currently. So if someone hade time to just tell me if this is okay or should I re-write it somehow?

```
foreach(Artist a in artists)
            {
                int i = 0;
                u.picArtistOne.ImageLocation = artists[i].artistPic;
                i++;
                u.picArtistTwo.ImageLocation = artists[i].artistPic;
                i++;
                u.picArtistThree.ImageLocation = artists[i].artistPic;
                i++;
                u.picArtistFour.ImageLocation = artists[i].artistPic;
                i++;
                u.picArtistFive.ImageLocation = artists[i].artistPic;
                i++;
                u.picArtistSix.ImageLocation = artists[i].artistPic;
                i++;
            }
```

Comment: I don't think the variable i add any value to your code.

Comment: Whatever `u` is should strcture its data differently.  Instead of one property per image, just maintain a collection of images, or a collection of `Artist`s, each with an image.

Comment: You don't even need `foreach` .. you are already incrementing `i` by yourself just fine.

Comment: I need the foreach to loop through my artists in order to get the value artistpic. And the "i" does add value indeed, that for every row in the database or every spot in the list.

Comment: `i` is only taking on the values 0-6 in your code (although the 6 is never being used). It's hard to tell *what* exactly you're trying to do, given the structure of this code.

Comment: Is there a reason you need member variables like `picArtistOne`, etc. rather than just a single variable holding an array of pictures?  Then you could do something like `u.artistPics[i] = artists[i].artistPic;` and it would actually be worthwhile to use a loop.

Comment: Are you doing anything with `a` at all?

Comment: the foreach loop here is worse than nothing.  You would be better off just hardcoding it.

Comment: Why are you `foreach`ing the `artists` collection when you're actually accessing the collection by index number anyways? The code is screaming to the programmer, "RTM, RTM..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a `foreach` on `artists` is next to useless here. You might want to just consider doing the following instead:

```
var index = 0;
Dictionary<int, PictureBox> pictureBoxes = u.Controls
                                            .OfType<PictureBox>
                                            .ToDictionary(key => index++)

for(var i = 0; i < index; i++)
{
  pictureBoxes[i].ImageLocation = artists[i].artistPic;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely insist on the fixed named attributes (and dont want to relflect them), at least remove all the foreach and i stuff:

```
u.picArtistOne.ImageLocation = artists[0].artistPic;
u.picArtistTwo.ImageLocation = artists[1].artistPic;
u.picArtistThree.ImageLocation = artists[2].artistPic;
u.picArtistFour.ImageLocation = artists[3].artistPic;
u.picArtistFive.ImageLocation = artists[4].artistPic;
u.picArtistSix.ImageLocation = artists[5].artistPic;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follow
instead of creating your picturebox you can create a flowLayoutPanel where those picture box should be and do like this

```
foreach(Artist artist in artists)
{
   PictureBox pic = new PictureBox();
   //Manually set the Size and SizeMode of your pictureBox here
   pic.ImageLocation = artist.artistPic;
   flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(pic);
}
```